# Specific matrix function task

Tags: c++, function, matrix

Let's say that I have a function to which I send these parameters. Reference on Matrix M (filled with 0 and 1), coordinate x, and coordinate y. f(M,x,y). x and y are coordinates of a cell in the matrix. The function has to return another matrix N with a 3x3 format. N has to be filled with the count of how many 1's are around every cell that is around (x,y). Please look at picture in order to understand better. [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXzcP.png) I do not know how to work my way around the matrix to get this information. Can someone please help me at least start? :D

Comment: *Can someone please help me at least start?* It will be better if you start and ask questions if you get stuck.

Answer (score -1):

### Matrix class

```
    

        class Matrix
        {
        private:
            int cols;
            int rows;
            int **cells;

        public:
            Matrix(const int& x , const int& y);         //constructor
            Matrix(const Matrix& M);                     //copy constructor
            int get_at(const int& x, const int& y)const;  //returns value from cell[x][y]
            void set_at(const int& x, const int& y);      //sets value in cell[x][y]
            int get_rows()const;                          //returns number of rows             
            int get_columns()const;                       //returns number of columns

        };
```

**Question:** How to get the cells in matrix M around cell[x][y]

**Answer:** cell[x+i][y+j] where i,j can be  -1 , 0 , 1, except the case where i = j = 0 because thats M[x][y] obviously.

You also need to consider that cell[x][y] can be on the edge of the matrix and for example: if **x=0 and y=0**, **cell[x-1][anythig]** or **cell[anything][y-1]** will result in an error(accessing a non existent cell).

This generally happens if:

- **x+i < 0 || x+i >= M.get_rows()** conclusion:  **x+i** is a non existing row position
- **y+j < 0 || y+j >= M.get_columns()** conclusion: **y+i** is a non existing column position

### Function count_ones

The next function counts the appearance of 1 in Matrix M around M.cell[x][y]

```
    

        int count_ones(const Matrix& M, const int& x , const int& y)
                {
                    int rows    = M.get_rows();
                    int columns = M.get_columns();

                    int count = 0;

            //iterate through all cells in Matrix M around M.cell[x][y]      
                    for( int i = -1 ; i <= 1 ; ++i)
                    {   
                        //check row existence
                        if( x + i < 0 || x + i >= rows )continue;

                        for(int j = -1 ; j <= 1 ; ++j)
                        { 

                        //check column existence and
                        //avoid counting  when i==0 && j==0 because thats M.cell[x][y]

                          if( y + j = columns || ( i==0 && j==0 ) )continue;

                          if(M.get_at(x+i,y+j) == 1 )++count;//checks M.cell[x+i][y+j]== 1

                        }

                    }

                    return count;
                }
```

### And finally the function you need

```
    

    Matrix f( const Matrix& M , const int& x , const int& y )
        {
            Matrix N(3,3);

            for(int i=-1 ; i <= 1 ; ++i  )//iterate around M.cell[x][y]
                for(int j=-1; j <= 1 ; ++j)//-------||-----------------
                {

         //Now count the 1's around the current cell M.cell[x+i][y+j]
         //and place the count number inside Matrix N at the right position 

                   N.set_at( i+1, j+1 , count_ones( M , x+i , y+j ) );

                }

            return N;// make sure you have a copy constructor or else this wont work 

            }
```